# how to replace a value in stack without losing other values?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have added 5 values in stack in the stack

```
student1.grades.Push(60);
student1.grades.Push(70);
student1.grades.Push(80);
student1.grades.Push(90);
student1.grades.Push(100);
```

I want to replace third value in stack without losing the above two values.
tried if condition to find the value in stack but didn't find any method in stack to replace it.

```
if (student1.grades.Contains(80)==true)
{
     // Unsure what to do here.
}
```

Comment: Pop all values above it, pop the value, push a new one, push back the values you popped earlier.

Comment: Pop all values till that values or if you don't want to do that use list for insertion and replacing

Comment: The question is, why are you using a stack if you don't want it to behave like a stack? Are you sure you don't want a `List<int>` instead?

Comment: You can create another stack, name BackupStudent push the first two value in it.And after replacing the value, pop these values and push them in old stack.

Comment: I'm with @LasseV.Karlsen a stack isn't intended for these in-place modifications, if you need to maintain ordering of addition and removal, perhaps a LinkedList might serve your purposes better? Or a List would do just fine.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i was just doing an exercise in the book so it has that question.i know i can do that in list using lambda expression finding the index and replacing it.

Comment: So it is an exercise, you want to know how to actually replace a value in a stack? Then my first comment is the answer.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i am beginner in c# just looked at different generic collections i can achieve it easily but the requirement was stack. yah the above solution is fine :) kudos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to replace a single value in a stack data structure you can use this algorithm:

Input is the original stack, let's call this STACK

1. Prepare a temporary stack, that starts empty, let's call this TEMP
2. Can we pop a single value from the STACK?

   1. If no, then go to step 5
3. Pop a single value from the STACK
4. Is it the value we want to replace?

   1. If it is, push back the value we want to replace with onto STACK and go to step 5
   2. If not, push it onto TEMP and go back to step 2
5. Push all values from TEMP back onto STACK

This will do what I said in the comment to your question: Pop all values above the value you want to replace, pop the value, push back the new value, push back all the values you popped earlier.

Here's a C# extension method for `Stack<T>` which will accomplish what you want:

```
public static class StackExtensions
{
    public static void Replace<T>(this Stack<T> stack, T valueToReplace, T valueToReplaceWith, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

        var temp = new Stack<T>();
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var value = stack.Pop();
            if (comparer.Equals(value, valueToReplace))
            {
                stack.Push(valueToReplaceWith);
                break;
            }
            temp.Push(value);
        }

        while (temp.Count > 0)
            stack.Push(temp.Pop());
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
student1.grades.Replace(80, 85);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't want to use a stack and instead want to use a List or maybe a Dictionary...

For example, what if there were two marks of 80? How would you know which one to remove??

You may want to have;

```
Dictionary<String, int> MarksBySubject
```

Then you can do like;

```
MarksBySubject.Add("Maths", 80);
```

and remove it like;

```
MarksBySubjects.Remove("Maths");
```